# Duplicate a record with related records in another table duplicated also

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a database(Access 2010) with about 6 tables related to 1 master table, and I would like to duplicate a record from the master table, and take with it the related tables from the other tables. Is there a simpler way to do this than my current method which involves:

- Find the next master ID number
- insert the old record with the new ID into the master table.
- Use the new ID number to insert into each of the related tables.

I am currently using VBA to find the new ID and run the SQL. I would prefer to run this a 1 SQL query, and I am running this from a button press, so VBA is not out of the question.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is possible that a data macro may suit : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973807.aspx --- http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3905921/Leveraging-Data-Macro-in-Microsoft-Access-2010.htm They are similar to triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that sounds about how you have to do it, as near as I know. 
Attempting to `UPDATE` would of course not leave any behind...

Your current solution (using VBA) is honestly probably your best bet; sure, you could use another language, or wrap it in a stored procedure, but you're still stuck with these exact steps.  It's pretty much a feature of the language (SQL) and systems (RDBMSs in general) design.